# Template Routes

Tags: template-routes

I'm using EE 3.0.5.

I have a template:
store/location

If there's a third segment, additional information is displayed via a conditional:
store/location/coupon

The template route is set to:
/location/{coupon:alpha_dash}  Require all Segments? = NO

But when I try to access /location, I get a 404 Error.

With the additional segment, /location/coupon, everything works fine.

How do I display the template without the last segment, /location?  Shouldn't Require all Segments? = NO allow the url without the last segment?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your `store/location` template contain any `{redirect="404"}` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be related not to Routes, but to template/URL rules in general.

If in your template preferences you have enabled 'Strict URLs' then at least 2 URL segments are required.

You can try overriding this by adding special route for /location

Comment: I think it is due to the Strict URLs and requiring 2 segments. Thanks for your help.